# Is it possible to read the output from any process using its PID?

Tags: command-line, process

Is it possible to attach a terminal to an already running process by using its PID in a similar fashion to using the `fg` command for jobs?

Comment: like what?! what is the process you want to attach?!

Comment: I would like to be able to view the output of a program that was started in another terminal

Answer (score 61):

You can get that process's standard file descriptors, e.g. `stdout`:

```
tail -f /proc/<pid>/fd/1
```

Comment: I tried this solution with top and it doesn't seem to work. In a terminal I launched top and in another I used your command with the corred pid but got no output.

Comment: How do you do this on a mac?

Comment: what about stderr? I assume /proc/<pid>/fd/2, but then how do you get both stdout/stderr?

Comment: What if this descriptor points to a socket? Tail can't read it. `# ls -la /proc/24510/fd/1
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Oct 31 08:34 /proc/24510/fd/1 -> socket:[444026]`

Comment: I had to `cat /proc/<pid>/fd/1` . For some reason `tail -f` didn't work for me

Answer (score 13):

There are a few options here. One is to redirect the output of the command to a file, and then use `tail` to view new lines that are added to that file in real time.

Another option is to launch your program inside of `screen`, which is a sort-of text-based terminal application. Screen sessions can be attached and detached, but are nominally meant only to be used by the same user, so if you want to share them between users.

Else if you wish you can trace the process and see what it is doing with `strace`:

```
strace -e trace=open -p 22254 -s 80 -o output.txt
```

- `-p PID`: Attach to the process with the process ID PID and begin tracing.
- `-s SIZE`: Specify the maximum string size to print (the default is 32).
- `-o filename`: Write the trace output to the file filename rather than to screen (stderr).

Comment: Finally it doesn`t seem to work. I launched top and in another I used your command with the corred pid but didn't get the expected output. When I use tail afterwards.

Comment: You need to use `sudo` with strace to attach to a process, and use `-o ~/output.txt` so the file is left in your home folder.

Comment: Use the output file, dont send to screen! Dont be an idiot like I was and press Ctrl-C to get out of strace and then detached my PID. Scared the shit out of me on an important script.

Answer (score 4):

You can use these commands given below to attach a running process on another terminal:

- `retty` (Man page: [retty](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/retty.1.html))
- `reptyr`
- `screen`

**Example:**

```
screen -S PID
retty $(pgrep PID)
reptyr PID
```

Comment: I was not able to find retty or reptry. Also, to be able to use screen I must launch the original process with it so it doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: you can install it using command `sudo apt-get install retty` but there are  few limitations with retty. Check out the man page mentioned in answer.