# Do programs in /bin or /usr/bin have to be invoked from a shell?

Tags: command-line, gnome-shell, tty

I started Chrome and Firefox from search bar and have found they were also opened from a terminal

```
$ pstree -aps 5221 | head -10
systemd,1 splash
  `-gdm3,1027
      `-gdm-session-wor,2418
          `-gdm-x-session,2529 --run-script env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu /usr/bin/gnome-session --session=ubuntu
              `-gnome-session-b,2545 --session=ubuntu
                  `-gnome-shell,2741
                      `-chrome,5221    
                          |-cat,5227
                          |-cat,5228
                          |-chrome,5232
```

Chrome was invoked from a GUI utility called `gnome-shell`.

Does any installed software have to run from a form of terminal?

Additionally, I have found the terminal I am working from is not named `tty` but

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/0
```

and can't communicate with `tty2`

```
$ echo "very strange long text" > /dev/tty2
$ grep -r  'very strange long text' /   2>/dev/null
```

However,  `grep` does not return the sent message. The text to tty2 is lost.

Comment: For future, please remember to separate questions, unless they're closely related. You have 3 question in one post: asking about `/usr/bin` and `/bin`, asking about `pts` , and communicating with `tty2`.    However, in this case they are related from what I see, as you have confusion as to how shell relates to `tty` device

Comment: Always glad to help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Do processes need a terminal ?

There are several things that you need to understand in order to answer this question:

- `/usr/bin` and `/bin` contain executable files
- [A shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)) is an interface to the user - it executes commands or performs functions that user wants; it is like levers and switches on a machine - you pull lever, and machine does something
- GNOME shell is GUI shell, `bash` is text-based shell. They are also processes, and can start new ones via `fork()` and `exec()` calls.

> Does any installed software have to run from a form of terminal?

No, not really. The very first process on the system, `/sbin/init` with PID 1 ( and that's `systemd` in your case), has no associated  [controlling terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/405755/85039). In fact, a [daemon](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/daemon.7.html) process does not have a controlling terminal. All processes on Linux are started via two syscalls - `fork()` and `exec()` - where you first create a "copy" of the original process, and then via `exec()` you run an executable, an applications in `/bin` and `/usr/bin`, or any other location you specify. Daemons can do exactly the same thing.

So in theory, I could make a daemon process that has no controlling terminal - no tty - and yet I could use `fork()` and then `exec()` to run something from `/usr/bin`. Of course, the command which I call has to be OK with that - some commands require having a controlling TTY in order to work.

In this question, it seems the big confusion is that shell is the same as tty, however they're different - `tty` designates a device (real or virtual), while shell - it's a process that interfaces with the user and the system to perform certain functions/actions.

---

#### Shell vs tty

Notice that the process name is `-gnome-shell,2741`. [Gnome Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Shell) is GUI shell, it is very different from typical text-based command interpreter such as `bash` or `ksh`.  You can start applications, files, windows, though you interact with it via shortcuts and mouse much more than with text-based shell.

The TTY you use `/dev/pts/0` and `/dev/tty2` are two different things entirely. Generally `/dev/ttyXX` indicates a console driver, and `/dev/tty2` is a device file which is also associated with special TTY driver. `/dev/tty[1-xx]` usually denote virtual consoles, which can be accessed via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1-7</kbd>. By default there are `tty1` to `tty7` open, with GUI on Ubuntu defaulting to `tty7`. On other distributions GUI may be on different tty, for instance if I recall correctly in Fedora it was `tty1`. Of course, there are ways to open more than 7 virtual consoles. See [Why so many virtual consoles?](https://askubuntu.com/a/817859/295286)

Every open tab and every new window of the terminal window you use within graphical shell - that will have  `/dev/pts/x` file associated. `pts` part stands for "pseudoterminal". These are involved with consoles that are implemented via software and don't represent real hardware, e.g. when you use terminal emulator or SSH connection.

It's also important to note that shells such as `bash` are *not* tty, the `/dev/tty2` is a device which has driver associated behind it. `/bin/bash` is an executable file, and is executed as command itself. While there are processes in kernel that manage `/dev/tty2` it is not a process; by contrast `/bin/bash` is a process that you can start. And this is in fact what happens when you open a terminal - your terminal window starts `/bin/bash` as process.

And of course, you can write to `/dev/tty2` or `/dev/pts/0` , if you have permission. For example, in order to use `/dev/ttyUSB0` or `/dev/ttyACM0` to write to Arduino or another embedded system, you have to belong to `dialout` group, which owns these special devices.  These two devices emulate serial console, so you can send data to the connected devices or program it. In case of special hardware devices like that, you also have to consider the speed or `baud rate` at which these devices read and send data.

#### See also

- [Do GUI based application execute shell commands in the background?](https://askubuntu.com/a/849312/295286)
- [Why is a virtual terminal “virtual”, and what/why/where is the “real” terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/14284/295286)
- [How to write to tty device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138342/how-to-read-write-to-tty-device)
- [Do OS GUI's have a different shell than the command line interpreter?](https://superuser.com/questions/1254950/do-os-guis-have-a-different-shell-than-the-command-line-interpreter)